# Recursive bind mount: Would later bind mounts in subtree be visible on Linux?

Tags: linux, mount

The [mount(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) manpage says:

> ```
>    MS_REC (since Linux 2.4.11)
>          Used in conjunction with MS_BIND to create a recursive
>          bind mount, and in conjunction with the propagation type
>          flags to recursively change the propagation type of all of
>          the mounts in a subtree.  See below for further details.
> ```

If I use `MS_REC`, would later bind mounts in the subtree be visible? For example:

1. Mount some directory `/home/my/mounted` to `/mnt/my/mount` with the `MS_BIND | MS_REC` flags.
2. Mount another directory `/home/my/submounted` to `/mnt/my/mounted/subtree` with the `MS_BIND` flag.

Would the content of `/home/my/submounted` be guaranteed to be visible in `/mnt/my/mount/subtree`? Is there any document reference that specifically discusses this?

A quick manual test answers yes, but an answer that is supported by some official docs is much appreciated.